# Alter input style when text entered using just CSS

Tags: html, css

I am styling a page where I have only been given access to the CSS files.

I am looking to alter the style of an input element if it's value is not blank.

Here's what I have so far...

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="myInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Card Number">
```

and

```
input {
    font-style:italic;  
}

input:not([value='']) {
    font-style:normal;  
}
```

This doesn't work though as the text is never italicised.

Is it even possible to achieve this taking into consideration I can only edit the CSS file.?

Comment: About the only solution you have here is to change it on `:focus`. But of course that won't be styled as soon as the input is blurred. You'll need to use JavaScript to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your code works (in Chrome at least) but only works if the value is set when the page loads since there's no change event to bind to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using **HTML5**...if so just edit your **PLACEHOLDER** tag

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {font-style: italic} /*Chrome */
:-moz-placeholder {font-style: italic} /*ff*/
:-ms-input-placeholder {font-style: italic} /*ie latest */
```

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/wCff9/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-style: italic;
}
input[type=text] {   
    font-style:normal;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Le6XM/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you looking to do is style the place holder. Give this a try!

```
        input {
            font-style:italic;  
        }

        ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            font-style:normal;  
        }

        :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
           font-style:normal;   
        }

        ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
           font-style:normal;  
        }

        :-ms-input-placeholder {  
           font-style:normal;   
        }
```